# Global objects in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop

How should I create multiple global instances of an object? From what I understand,(and forgive me if I'm wrong) a singleton will only let me create 1 instance of the class.

Comment: What are those multiple global instances of a class doing in your case?

Comment: How about a singleton of NSArray of your global objects?

Comment: Try and avoid the word global, it gives the natives diarrhea...

Answer (score 1):

There are many Cocoa classes that expose global instances, but aren't true singletons in the sense that there can only ever be one of them. Consider `NSTimeZone` for example. There are globally accessible instances like `localTimeZone`, `defaultTimeZone`, and `systemTimeZone`, but you can also create as many additional time zone objects as you like.

You can easily use a similar pattern for your own classes by making multiple class methods that allow you to access specific, global instances. In fact, this is actually easier than making a *true* singleton that would prevent the creation of more than one instance.

Comment: `+ (ClassName *)sharedClassName{static ClassName *sharedClassName = nil; static dispatch_once_t onceToken; dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{sharedClassName = [[ClassName alloc] init];}); return sharedClassName;}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this, assuming the class in question is called `PFXObject`:

```
static NSMutableArray *sharedObjects = nil;
+ (PFXObject *)newSharedObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger *)indexOut
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    });
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    PFXObject *newObject = [[PFXObject alloc] init];
    @synchronized(sharedObjects) {
        [sharedObjects addObject:newObject];
        index = sharedObjects.count - 1;
    }
    if (indexOut) {
        *indexOut = index;
    }
    return newObject;
}

+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    PFXObject *object = nil;
    @synchronized(sharedObjects) {
        object = [sharedObjects objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return object;
}
```

This will allow you to create as many shared instances of `PFXObject` as you want and retrieve them by index.  Alternatively, you might want to use a dictionary:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *sharedObjects = nil;
+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)key
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    });
    PFXObject *object = nil;
    @synchronized(sharedObjects)
    {
        if (!(object = sharedObjects[key])) {
            object = [[PFXObject alloc] init];
            sharedObjects[key] = object;
        }

    }
    return object;
}
```

This will allow you to have arbitrarily many shared objects and have each be associated with a key of your choosing.

---

Edit: You wrote

> can you explain how I would use this and init the objects

To use this mechanism, you would write

```
PFXObject *sharedObject = [PFXObject sharedObjectForKey:theKey];
```

to get the shared `PFXObject` that corresponds to the key `theKey` (an instance of some class that implements `NSCopying` and (almost certainly) overrides `-hash`) anywhere that you wanted to use the shared object.  All that you need to do in any file in which you want to use a shared instance is `#import` the appropriate header file (in this case `PFXObject.h`) and be sure to declare the class method (`sharedObjectForKey:`) in the `@interface` in that file:

```
//PFXObject.h

@interface PFXObject : NSObject
//...
+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)theKey;
//...
@end
```

---

**Edit**: Example

The following sample program demonstrates instantiating a shared `PFXObject` using `+sharedObjectForKey:`

```
@interface PFXObject : NSObject
+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)key;
@end

@implementation PFXObject
static NSMutableDictionary *sharedObjects = nil;
+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)key
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    });
    PFXObject *object = nil;
    @synchronized(sharedObjects)
    {
        if (!(object = sharedObjects[key])) {
            object = [[PFXObject alloc] init];
            sharedObjects[key] = object;
        }
    }
    return object;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool {  
        PFXObject *sharedObject = [PFXObject sharedObjectForKey:@"key"];
        NSLog(@"%@", sharedObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how I would use this and init the objects

Comment: See my edit.  Notice the change made to the dictionary approach.

Comment: how would I access the objects?

Comment: @MowelBovement To get the shared object corresponding to a given key (for example `NSString *theKey = @"theKey"`), you would write `PFXObject *sharedObject = [PFXObject sharedObjectForKey:theKey];`.  If no shared object had yet been created corresponding to that key, the object would be created at that point.

Comment: Your method is giving me an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'key'"

Comment: What line is it giving you that error on?

Comment: See my edit for a sample usage.  As that sample demonstrates, the method provided, `+[PFXObject sharedObjectForKey:]`, works as intended.

Comment: I'm getting the error on the `if (!(object = sharedObjects[key])` line and the `sharedObjects[key] = object;` line.

Comment: In the code that I've posted here, the identifier `key` is declared as the only argument to the method: `+ (PFXObject *)sharedObjectForKey:(id<NSCopying>)key`.  Did you change this variable name?  What do you have as the first line of your implementation?